# Parse RNA variant effect annotations ("r." format)

Tags: rna, variation, rna-splicing, variants

I've got annotations for splicing variants in a format like this (this is one variant):

- *Variant:* NM_004092.3:c.88+5G>A
- *Effect:* Retention; r.87_88ins1_88+10:p.(Ala31Glufs*23)

I want to extract which acceptor/donor sites are lost or gained (in this case lost causing intron retention). In other words, the genomic location of the sequence that is retained in mRNA.

I parsed the variant HGVS ID using ensembl VEP (like [this](https://rest.ensembl.org/vep/human/hgvs/NM_004092.3:c.88+5G%3EA?content-type=application/json)) without problems, giving me the genomic location of this variant. However, VEP seems to not like "r." annotations for the effect: I tried ensembl VEP again with [RNA](https://rest.ensembl.org/vep/human/hgvs/NM_004092.3:r.87_88ins1_88+10?content-type=application/json), [protein](https://rest.ensembl.org/vep/human/hgvs/NM_004092.3:p.(Ala31Glufs*23)?content-type=application/json), and [both](https://rest.ensembl.org/vep/human/hgvs/NM_004092.3:r.87_88ins1_88+10:p.(Ala31Glufs*23)?content-type=application/json) annotations, none of which worked.

Is there a tool that can parse these annotations for me? I've got too many to do it by hand.

---

**Note on RNA splicing**

RNA splicing and acceptor and donor sites:

An introns contains: a 5' donor site, a branch site located near the 3' site and a 3' acceptor site. Both the donor and acceptor  are required for splicing along with the branch site.